# requires module file in same directory but reports error

Tags: node.js

There are 2 javascript files a.js b.js in same directory

b.js

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    return new B(app);
};


var B = function(app) {



};
```

a.js

```
var configCouchbase = require('b.js')();
```

but it reports

```
Caught exception: Error: Cannot find module 'b.js'
```

Your comment welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to do `require('./b.js')` - otherwise it looks module in ./node_modules/b.js ( and if not found - in ../node_modules/b.js etc)